# Determining width and length from CMOS inverter layout

Tags: inverter, cmos, layout

How do I determine the width and length from the following cmos inverter layout, given that lambda=0.25um? The answer is Wn=1.0um, Ln=0.25um, Wp=0.5um, and Lp=0.25um. I know that the length is equal to 2 x lambda, but I do not understand how to get width from the layout.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the metal-poly contacts are also 2lambda.

Then the left width is 1+2+2+2+1 = 8 lambda, or 1 micron.

By the way, most inverters, because Pmobility ~~ 1/2 of Nmobility, will have the Pwidth about 2X the Nwidth.

Comment: Thank you so much!